# Filter grep output

Tags: scripting, grep

Using `grep "val" index.php` I get the list

```
<td class=val>   7.6</td>
<td class=val>  58</td>
<td class=val>1013.8 </td>
<td class=val> 1020 </td>
<td class=val>   0.2</td>
<td class=val>   2.4</td>
```

I'd like to filter and get only the value of the first `td`, that is, **7.6** and save it to use later with `echo`.

That value could change, so `grep "7.6"` is not good.

**(!)** The line in `php` containing that tag is line 42. A solution without this information could be better since the line number could change. But for a while, using its number can be a temporary solution.

I searched for a solution but I only found complex ones.

Comment: `grep -m1 "=val" index.php | grep -o "[0-9.]*"`

Comment: @Costas, thanks so much. It works perfectly. If you wish, please, post it as answer.

Comment: @Costas, sometimes the number I want to get is negative *-7.6* for example. And in this case, the grep returns empty. How to grep for the number (and its signal it there is one)?

Comment: `grep -wo "\-\?[0-9.]\+"`

Answer (score 1):

Using (gnu)grep:

```
grep -m1 -oP '(?<=class=val>).*?(?=</td>)'

grep -m1 -oP 'class=val>\s*\K[0-9.]*'        # \cite{Costas)
```

Comment: `grep -m1 -oP 'class=val>\s*\K[0-9.]*'`